# Android: bbcode to html and format inside a listview

Tags: java, android, listview, formatting

What I'm trying to do is to format bbcode tags and displaying the right html tag inside a listview. What i've done works with a single textview but not inside a listview.

Thank you.

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/268/dhe6.png

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/838/kdjq.png

```
    public void updateJSONData() {
    messageList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(POST_URL);
        resultMainMessage = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_POST);
        for (int i = 0; i < resultMainMessage.length(); i++) {
            mainMessage = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject = resultMainMessage.getJSONObject(i);


            String body = JSONObject.getString(TAG_BODY);

            String user = JSONObject.getString(TAG_POSTER_NAME);
            ID_TOPIC = JSONObject.getString(TAG_ID_TOPIC);
            ID_BOARD = JSONObject.getString(TAG_ID_BOARD);

            long date = Long.parseLong(JSONObject.getString(TAG_POSTER_TIME));
            Date postDate = new Date(date * 1000L);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
            mainMessage.put(TAG_BODY, ""+Html.fromHtml(HtmlParser.bbcode(body)));
            mainMessage.put(TAG_POSTER_NAME, user);
            mainMessage.put(TAG_POSTER_TIME, sdf.format(postDate));

            messageList.add(mainMessage);
            messageList.get(i);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Impossibile connettersi.\n Controlla lo stato della connessione", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Impossibile connettersi.\n Controlla lo stato della connessione", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

method for the listview adapter

```
public void updateList(int start, int end) {


    ListView messages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.body);
    ListAdapter mainMessage = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), messageList.subList(start, end), R.layout.messages, new String[]{
            TAG_BODY, TAG_POSTER_NAME, TAG_POSTER_TIME
    }, new int[]{R.id.body, R.id.userName, R.id.postDate});
    messages.setAdapter(mainMessage);
}
```

Html parser class

```
public class HtmlParser {
  public static String bbcode(String text) {
    String html = text;
    Map<String,String> bbMap = new HashMap<String , String>();
    bbMap.put("\\[quote author=(.+?) link=topic=(.+?) date=(.+?)\\](.+?)\\[/quote\\]", "<blockquote>$4</blockquote>");

    for (Map.Entry entry: bbMap.entrySet()) {
        html = html.replaceAll(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue().toString());
    }

    return html;
  }
}
```